# Category Grouping

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

I'm having trouble grouping some items. Here are examples of incorrect and correct grouping:

[image]

asp.net code:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var menu = db.reportmenu;
    var Reportmenu = menu.ToList();

    return View(Reportmenu);
}
```

HTML:

```
@model IEnumerable<Pandora2._0.Models.reportmenu>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <h6 class="collapse-header">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.categoria)</h6>
    <a class="collapse-item" href="~/Reports/EmbedReport?id=@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.reportid)">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.nome)</a>    
}
```

Comment: `var menu = db.reportmenu.GroupBy(item => item.categoria)`

Comment: @RufusL: tipo'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[System.Linq.IGrouping`2[System.String,Pandora2._0.Models.reportmenu]]', mas esse dicionário requer um item do tipo 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Pandora2._0.Models.reportmenu]'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this

```
@model IEnumerable<Pandora2._0.Models.reportmenu>

@{
var Reportmenu = Model.GroupBy(a=> a.categoria, (key,g) => new 
    {
        Key = key,
        Data = g.ToList()
    }).ToList();
}


@foreach (var item in Reportmenu)
{
    <h6 class="collapse-header">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Key)</h6>
    @foreach(var name in item.Data)
    {
        <a class="collapse-item" href="~/Reports/EmbedReport?id=@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => name.reportid)">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => name.nome)</a>    
    }
}
```